# Login using Facebook login button and start a new activity

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I want to start a new activity after facebook login.
I want an application that have a facebook login button and after login enter in other activity, in this tutorial after I click on login button the logout button appears and I don't want the logout button appear.
This is my code. I am using facebook-android-sdk 4.1.2
Test is the new activity class.I want to open it after facebook login.

```
TextView info;
private LoginButton loginButton;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
String name;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    setContentView(R.layout.fb_button);
    info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
    loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_friends"));

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
          GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {
                            // Application code

                            try {
                           // URL image_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture" );
                                name = object.getString("email");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            // getting email of the use
                           info.setText(name);

                            Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
            Intent intent = new Intent(FbActivity.this, Test.class);
            FbActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

            info.setText("Login attempt canceled.");

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

            info.setText("Login attempt failed.");

        }
    });

    // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask

}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   Intent intent = new Intent(FbActivity.this, Test.class);
            FbActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Write -

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
    Intent intent = new Intent(FbActivity.this, Test.class);
    FbActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

on completion, for ex. -

```
   @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
          GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {
                            // Application code

                            try {
                           // URL image_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture" );
                                name = object.getString("email");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            // getting email of the use
                           info.setText(name);


                 Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                 parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday"); 
                 request.setParameters(parameters);
                 request.executeAsync();
                 Intent intent = new Intent(FbActivity.this, Test.class);
                 FbActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

                 Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: When i click on continue on the confirm login page of facebook to open a new activity it first shows my previous activity for few seconds and then open the actual activity. Can you please help ?

Comment: you should add your question separately with logs and code

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this line to your code after login.

```
loginButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Remember after logout to show button with

```
loginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```